# display an array of results in a PHP Variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable (`$email_body`) which has the body of an email in it. just before this variable i am running this PHP:

```
$sql3="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive where sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
$rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn);
while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
{
    $invoices_list_data[] = $result3["invoice_number"];
}
$invoices_list = implode('<br>',$invoices_list_data);
```

i want to make it list all the rows found (`invoice_number` column) in the `$email_body` variable

so i have tried:

```
$email_body = $invoices_list;
```

but its only displaying one row

how can i do this?

Comment: I don't see $email_body in your code :)

Comment: $invoices_list variable already has all the invoice_number found in the table.

Comment: no it doesn't - thats why i am having a problem

Comment: @user2710234 have you checked your query, does it return result(s)?

Comment: if i echo $invoices_list it returns one row but if i run the query in the database it returns more

Comment: echo $invoices_list_data this and tell the value;

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem probably lies in debugging the query.  First try and debug your code step by step.

```
$sql3="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive where sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";

echo $sql3;
```

The above should output your sql statement. Something like

> SELECT * FROM billing_pdf_archive WHERE sequence = 'val'

Try connecting to your database and running it in mysql query browser.  Does it return **multiple** results?  If so continue to next step.

```
$rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn);
while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
{
    var_dump($result3);
    $invoices_list_data[] = $result3["invoice_number"];
}
```

The above should output values. If it does then you are on your way to next step.  Your implode should join the values up.